# Reduce method in order to count object values with a specific keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array like this:

```
const teamsPoints = [
  {team1_game00: 1},
  {team1_game01: 2},
  {team1_game02: 3},
  {team2_game00: 0},
  {team2_game10: 2},
  {team2_game11: 3},
  {team3_game01: 0},
  {team3_game10: 0},
  {team3_game20: 3},
  {team4_game02: 0},
  {team4_game11: 0},
  {team4_game20: 0}
]
```

What I'm trying to get is:

```
{
  team1: 6,
  team2: 5,
  team3: 3,
  team4: 0
}
```

which is the sum of points of every team.

I was trying to achieve that by using reduce method.

```
const scoreResult = teamsPoints.reduce((total, current) => {    

}, {});
```

As I understand I'm starting with an empty object, but then I have a problem to get proper key-value pairs (that's why I have not published it here, must admin reduce method is a kinda new thing to me).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a small sample using `reduce`. I basically get the name of the team, use it as a key in the reduced result and increment its value!

Hope this will help you ;) Feel free to ask me anything if it's not clear!

```js
const teamsPoints = [
{team1_game00: 1},
{team1_game01: 2},
{team1_game02: 3},
{team2_game00: 0},
{team2_game10: 2},
{team2_game11: 3},
{team3_game01: 0},
{team3_game10: 0},
{team3_game20: 3},
{team4_game02: 0},
{team4_game11: 0},
{team4_game20: 0}
];

const scoreResult = teamsPoints.reduce((total, game) => {
  const [gameName] = Object.keys(game);
  const [team] = gameName.split('_');
  total[team] = total[team] || 0;
  total[team] += game[gameName];
  return total;
}, {});

console.log(scoreResult);
```

Comment: Just one question: why do you use brackets here: const [gameName]?

Comment: Either you do this: `const [gameName] = Object.keys(game);` or this: `const gameName = Object.keys(game)[0];` and the first is more modern and elegant :) It's part of the last ES features: http://es6-features.org/#ArrayMatching

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `reduce` to group the teams.

```js
const teamsPoints = [{team1_game00: 1},{team1_game01: 2},{team1_game02: 3},{team2_game00: 0},{team2_game10: 2},{team2_game11: 3},{team3_game01: 0},{team3_game10: 0},{team3_game20: 3},{team4_game02: 0},{team4_game11: 0},{team4_game20: 0}],
      result = teamsPoints.reduce((a, c) => {
        let keys = Object.keys(c),
            [key] = keys[0].split('_');
        a[key] = (a[key] || 0) + c[keys[0]];
        return a;
      }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

So generally I wouldn't use reduce for this, just because of how the objects are organized. You wouldn't really want to signify what game and what team it is in the same object, but if you did have those objects like that I would first create a second object to store the totals, and do the following

```
let totals = {};

teamsPoints.map(obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
    if (totals.hasOwnProperty(key.split('_')[0])) {
       totals[key.split('_')[0]] += obj[key];
    } else {
      totals[key.split('_')[0]] = obj[key];
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to map the array at first in order to have set of [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
const res = teamsPoints
    .map(val => Object.entries(val)[0])
    .map(([key, val]) => [key.split('_')[0], val])
    .reduce((init, [team, count]) => Object.assign(init, { [team]: (init[team] || 0) +  count }), {});
```